# How to distinguish Move from undoMove?

Tags: optaplanner

In one step of lets say local search OptaPlanner evaluates N different moves by doing the move and then calling the undoMove and then at the end making the best move from the N evaluated.Is there a way to find out when is the move and when is the undoMove?

Comment: Where do you want to find that out? In the log? In a custom move implementation? In the debugger in the code? And why?

Comment: I just wanted to find out is the score recalculated every time the undoMove is made in a given step.Of course it will not make sense because we have it calculated at the beginning of the step and it will be redundant. And i also have custom variable listeners implemented for custom shadow variables and i wanted to find out if they get triggered when the undoMove is made to return everything to normal. So as i found out the score is not calculated when the undoMove is called and the variable listeners get triggered as normal and set the solution to the previous state.

Comment: So is there a way to find out when it is a Move and when it is an undoMove? I need to know this in the variableListeners because in them i have code that finds out what is the best value for the shadow variable to be assigned at the moment. I know this is maybe not the best way but it works for me.So what i need is when its a Move to remember the value of the shadow variable (OLD VALUE),calculate the new value , set it  and then when the undoMove is called the OLD VALUE which is remembered will be retrieved.

Comment: Because if doing the calculation to find the value for the shadow variables value it may have a new value which is different than the value before the move was done.

Comment: "if doing the calculation to find the value for the shadow variables value it may have a new value which is different than the value before the move was done." => That's an illegal shadow variable. A shadow variable is in essence the result of a formula/algo based on at least 1 planning variable (and maybe some problem properties). The same planning variables state should always deliver the exact same shadow variable state.

Comment: Given a shape and the position of the sun, the shadow is always the same, no matter if the shape has changed an unchanged meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable listeners are triggered at the end of the undoMove (because every move must do `ScoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners()` as of 6.3).

By default, the score is not recalculated after the undoMove (as it can be predicted so it's a waste of perfomrance). However with enviromnentMode FAST/FULL_ASSERT it is, but not with NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT. Of course, you shouldn't use those to enforce score recalculation after undo moves: you should never rely on the score being recalculating after undo moves.